# Python extract list of unknow length

Tags: python

I have a string from user. It must containt a comma to split by it and assign to variables. But what if user miss a comma? Surely I can check len of splitted string in if-else branches, but maybe there is another way, I mean assignment during list has a values. For example

```
a, b, c, d, e = list(range(3))  # 'a' and 'b' are None or not exists
```

Comment: pls paste the string and expected output

Comment: Why exactly do you want to put the values in separate variables? Why not just use a list?

Comment: In this example, is the user required to have exactly 5 comma separated values? If so, you could catch the raised `ValueError` and prompt the user to try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> alist=list(range(3))
>>> alist
[0, 1, 2]
>>> a,b,c,*d=alist
>>> a,b,c
(0, 1, 2)
>>> d
[]
```

If there are no more elements, `d` is an empty list. It uses the *unpacking operator `*`*. Not the best possible solution for large lists, so I would still define a function for that. For small cases, it works well. (You could assume that is `d==[]`, there are no more elements in `alist`)For example, you could add:

```
return False if not d else return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are free to extend the list with None values before extraction.

```
li = list(range(3))
expected_size = 5
missing_size = expected_size - len(li)
none_li = [None] * missing_size
new_li = li + none_li
a, b, c, d, e = new_li
```